# How to solve laravel notification with broadcast ? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-5.3, broadcast

My controller is like this :

```
public function add($param)
{
    ...
    $message = Message::create([
        ...
        'created_at'            => Carbon::now(),
        'updated_at'            => Carbon::now()
    ]);
    Notification::send($notify_to, new MessageInsert($message));
    dd($message);
    return $message;
}
```

My MessageInsert is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
class MessageInsert extends Notification implements ShouldBroadcast, ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    private $data;
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['broadcast','database','mail'];
    }
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'id'        => $this->data->id,
            ...
        ];
    }
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->greeting('Hello!')
            ->line('...')
            ->action('...')
            ->line('Thank you!');
    } 
}
```

If like this :

> return ['broadcast','database','mail'];

The result of `dd($message);` is error

But if like this :

> return ['database','mail'];

The result of `dd($message);` is array of `$message`

Why there is error when I use broadcast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try adding the toBroadcast function?

```
public function toBroadcast($notifiable) {
return new BroadcastMessage([ 'invoice_id' => $this->invoice->id, 'amount' => $this->invoice->amount, ]);
}
```